# Change FPS in flash without speeding up animation

Tags: flash, adobe-cs4, adobe-flash

Does anyone know how to change the fps of an fla without speeding up the animation. I need to hand it over to a video editor and he needs the fps to be 59.94 fps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Video Editor Person can't handle the conversion then he or she is in the wrong job. If someone were to require such of me I would assume that they were either incompetent or trying to make me go away.

Ask the VEP if they want that interlaced or not. Ask if they want a 2-3 pulldown or something like a 2-5 pulldown.  Ask if they need SMPTE or Manchester timecodes, and if SMPTE, does VEP need 12M-2 or can VPE make do with 12M-1?

Your question isn't stupid, what was asked of you kinda is.

Comment: haha that is kind of how I felt too but this is my first time doing this so I wasn't sure. This is my first time working with a video editor so I really appreciate the feedback. You rock!